# How to reassemble a sentence from its list of split words?

Tags: java, string, search

I have a random sentence, then I split the sentence (using % character) into chunks where every chunk is two characters (including white space and punctuations) wide. Then I shuffle chunks. Now, the question is how to reassemble the sentence? 
Here is an example:
"I enjoyed my dinner tonight."
splitting the sentence: %I %en%jo%ye%d %my% d%in%ne%r %to%ni%gh%t.%
Shuffling the chunks: %r %en%ye%d % d%in%to%my%ni%gh%ne%t.%jo%I %

Now, how do I reassemble the sentence form these chunks? %r %en%ye%d % d%in%to%my%ni%gh%ne%t.%jo%I %

My first thought is to first recognize words and then rebuild the sentence. The number of words can be guess from the number of spaces we have. In the above example, there are 4 spaces, then there would be 5 words. There is also a dictionary of all words in English that can be used. 
Please give me your thought about how to reassemble words.
Thanks!

Comment: Sure, that every chunk is 2 characters wide? You have several that consist only of one character.

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to mention that characters can be space and punctuations.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Many times there will be more than one way to form a valid sentence and there is no way to tell which one corresponds to the original.

Comment: For sure the solution will have some errors. It wouldn't be 100% accurate. Regardless, any idea how to reassemble words?

Comment: Do you intend to assemble the shuffled chunks into an anagram of the original sentence, or to recover the original sentence itself? If you're trying to use the second one to encode a message it's easier and safer to pass the encoding algorithm along with the encoded message than recover it by a brute force attack

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through the list of words using a for loop and then append each consecutive index to a string variable.

```
for(String s : list)
{
completeSentance += s;
}
```

Comment: considering the size of dictionary (100B words) a brute force search is not scalable and an efficient solution.

Comment: @Ggrimerz That is not what the question really asks. The real challenge is to  find a way to rearrange the chunks in the original order

Comment: you can use StringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to derive all the information, that is still left in the chunks, and then use some kind of (intelligent) brutforce.

For the following I assume that every chunk is 2 characters wide, and that `.`,`!`,`?` are used at the end of the sentence, commas and semicolons within the sentence. After a comma or semicolon, there is a space. I further assume that all sentences that are considered here, can be cut into 2 character wide chunks.

May `x` be an arbitrary character, and `_` denotes a space.

### Let's take a look at what we know:

- `x_`, if the space is at the end, the chunk forms a word ending, or a word that consists of only one character. `X_` with an uppercase letter, is also a candidate for the sentence's first word, with exception of `I_`, or other one char words, that are written in capital letters and can occur in the middle of the sentence.
- `_x`, if the space is at the beginning, the character is a word prefix. It is not the first chunk of the sentence, and **not** the last chunk.
- `x!`, `x?`, `x.` and combinations with other punctuation marks that delimit a sentence are the **last chunk** of the sentence

---

- `x´` forms a genitive for words ending with an `s` sound, so this is another word ending, if
  `x` has an `s` sound.
- `x´` if `x` does not have a `s` sound, it forms a regular genitive and a furter `s_` chunk is to be expected.
- `´s` is an wordending of a word in genitive case.

**NOTE**

I've applied these apostrophe rules only to genetive, but they are cases like `they're` and so on. You have to create rules for these cases to, if you want to include them. Maybe it would be easier to avoid these short forms for the beginning.

---

- number of words is number of `_` + 1, but only if there are spaces after commas and semicolons!

Maybe can add more rules, e. g. `a_` or `_a` has a rather chance of forming a word on its own, but it could also be just a word end or start.

After you have all the rules, apply the ones that are bullet proof. Find the last chunk of the sentences by use of the puctuation rule. Find the word beginnings, and the word endings. Exclude as much as possible. After you can't exclude anything anymore, start the bruteforcing, but don't search for all words, only words that can be built with the characters that are still open to form a word.